# Grid positioning with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i have the following simple grid made possible with flexbox.

[image: Flexbox grid]

```css
* {
  color: white;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #00003b;
}
.green {
  background-color: #002700;
}
.red {
  background-color: #800000;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #1e001e;
}
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.container > div {
  display: flex;
}
.elemUno {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.elemDos {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
.elemTres {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container blue">
  <div class="elemUno left red">
    Elem 1
  </div>
  <div class="elemDos left green">
    Elem 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container blue">
  <div class="elemTres left purple">
    Elem 3
  </div>

</div>
```

What i want is to have a div that pretty much uses the blue space AS A DIV without breaking the rows height. is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to add a div which takes the rest of the blue space. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @ManojKumar you are correct

Comment: Not possible with the current markup. You have two containers split. So adding a div would take either of the container's blue space.